# how to send otp on mobile and open enter otp popup window on single button click

Tags: c#

I have single button and by clicking on that single button i want send OTP on registered number and opening popup window to enter OTP on same button. It can be send OTP and open popup but here problem is that after sending OTP it can refresh the page and popup window is gone.I want to write OTP in popup.How it can be take.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button5" class="btn btn-info" OnClick="Button6_Click" runat="server" Text="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" >

    <div class="modal-content" >
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center;">Enter OTP</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

  <center><input type="text" class="text form-control1" id="TextBox1" runat="server"  name="Email" placeholder="Enter Your OTP"  /></center>

           <br />
              <center>  <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button8_Click" class="btn-success btn" />    </center>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

   <%-- <asp:Button ID="Button1" class="btn btn-default"   runat="server"  Text="Yes"  onclick="Button1_Click"/>--%>


    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

```
 protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {

  con.Open();
  Random random = new Random();

  int num = random.Next(1, 10000);


  TextBox1.Value = Convert.ToString(num);

  otp = TextBox1.Value;

  string id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
  //string id = "1";
  MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("Update owner set otp=@otp where owner_id='" + id + "'", con);
  cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@otp", TextBox1.Value);
  cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();


  string strUrl = "https://www.logonutility.in/app/smsapi/index.php?key=3579F54FC00CF5&campaign=8614&routeid=20&type=text&contacts=" + owner_phone.Value + "&senderid=MWWCLT&msg= OTP for Shivneri site is :" + otp + ". Do not share it with anyone. Sent via-http://www.mywebworldsms.com ";


  WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(strUrl);
  // Get the response back  
  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
  Stream s = (Stream)response.GetResponseStream();
  StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(s);
  string dataString = readStream.ReadToEnd();
  response.Close();
  s.Close();
  readStream.Close();

  //Response.Write("<script>alert('Otp Send Successfully');window.location.href='otp.aspx?mobile=" + Label2.Text + "&owner_id=" + id + "' </script>");

  con.Close();

 //Response.Redirect("owner_detail.aspx");
}



protected void Button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();


    string mob = Request.QueryString["owner_phone"].ToString();
    string b = Request.QueryString["owner_id"].ToString();


    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM owner WHERE owner_phone ='" + mob + "' And owner_id='" + b + "'", con);

    MySqlDataReader dt = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dt.Read())
    {
        string a = TextBox1.Value;

        if (a == dt["otp"].ToString())
        {

            Response.Redirect("updateowner.aspx?m_id=" + b);
        }
        else
        {

            Response.Write("<script>alert(' Please enter correct OTP');</script>");


        }

    }
    dt.Close();
    con.Close();

}
```